# Qt 6.6.1 WebAssembly. The background color of the parent window is changed to black

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, webassembly

I have a main window to place an OpenGL widget on it. The background color of the parent window is changed to black:

[image]

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QtGui/QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QtOpenGLWidgets/QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

class OpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, private QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    void initializeGL() override
    {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    }

    void paintGL() override
    {
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.3f, 0.2f, 1.f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow()
    {
        setWindowTitle("OpenGL, Qt6, C++");
        resize(300, 300);

        m_nameLabel = new QLabel("Click on object or background");
        m_nameLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Policy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Policy::Fixed);
        OpenGLWidget *openGLWidget = new OpenGLWidget();

        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        layout->addWidget(m_nameLabel);
        layout->addWidget(openGLWidget);
        // layout->addStretch();
        setLayout(layout);
    }

private:
    QLabel *m_nameLabel;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

pro

```
QT += core gui openglwidgets widgets

win32: LIBS += -lopengl32

CONFIG += c++17

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

TARGET = app
```

But it works without the problem on Desktop:

[image]

And on physical device with Android:

[image]

Cross-ref: https://forum.qt.io/topic/153377/qt-6-6-1-webassembly-background-color-of-parent-window-is-changed-to-black

**Added:**

If I don't add the `openGLWidget`:

```cpp
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        layout->addWidget(m_nameLabel);
        // layout->addWidget(openGLWidget);
        layout->addStretch();
        setLayout(layout);
```

the color is normal:

[image]

Comment: I created a bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-120651

Comment: I attached a zip to the bug report above.